# ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty in lambda function using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to perform update operation using lambda function. But am getting Validation Exception stating  **ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty**

**Iam just assigning the interface to vehicleInfo**

```
 export interface VehicleFeatureUpdateRequest{
    year: number;
    model: string;
    controls:Controls;
}



private doUpdate = (vehicle: VehicleFeatureUpdateRequest) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const vehicleInfo = vehicle;
            const updates:Controls = vehicle.controls;
            console.log(vehicleInfo);               
            const ddbParams: DocumentClient.UpdateItemInput = {
                TableName: this.ConfigParams['vehicletable'],


                Key:{
                    model:vehicleInfo.model,
                    year:vehicleInfo.year
                },

                UpdateExpression: "set controls = :controls",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                   ":controls":updates 
                },

                ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"

            };


            this.DDB.update(ddbParams, (err: AWSError, data: DocumentClient.UpdateItemOutput) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error updating an item in vehicle table: ' + err, err.stack);
                    return reject(err);
                }
                data['status'] = `Vehicle [${vehicleInfo.model}] was updated successfully.`;
                return resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

> Response:
>       {
>         "errorType": "ValidationException",
>         "errorMessage": "ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty",
>         "trace": [
>           "ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty",
>           "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)",
>           "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
>           "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
>           "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
>           "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
>           "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
>           "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
>           "    at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
>           "    at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
>           "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
>         ]
>       }

Comment: Can you share the complete output? Specifically what is the value of the vehicleInfo variable?

Comment: What's the purpose of `const updates:Controls = vehicle.controls`?